# javascript/Typescript return inside .then callback inside array.filter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to filter an array but to do that I need to call my database that returns a promise. 
Code:

```
this.arrayToFilter.filter(myObject => {
    this.dataBaseService.getSomething(myObject.id).then(something => {
        // some calculations
        return shouldBeFiltered 
    })
})
```

How can I get the value of `shouldBeFiltered` to the filter callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an array of Promises and call `Promise.all` on it before filtering:

```
const shouldBeFilteredArr = await Promise.all(
  this.arrayToFilter.map(({ id }) => this.dataBaseService.getSomething(id)
);
const filteredItems = this.arrayToFilter.filter((myObject, i) => {
  const something = shouldBeFilteredArr[i];
  // some calculations
  return shouldBeFiltered;
});
```